# How to make a C# web service accepts a custom object including unbound elements defined in XSD

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm implementing a C# web service that is supposed to accept a custom message including unbounded number of elements.

Originally, the object is defined in a XSD file like below:

```
<xsd:element name="LogMessage">  
<xsd:complexType>  
<xsd:sequence>  
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="avantlog" type="tns:LogEventType">  
</xsd:element>  
</xsd:sequence>  
</xsd:complexType>  
</xsd:element>  
<xsd:complexType name="LogEventType">  
<xsd:sequence>  
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="context" type="tns:ContextType">  
</xsd:element>   
</xsd:sequence>  
</xsd:complexType>  
<xsd:complexType name="ContextType">  
<xsd:sequence>  
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="severity" type="xsd:string">  
</xsd:element>  
</xsd:sequence>  
</xsd:complexType>
```

And, in a CS file implementing the web service, I prepared a struct for this:

```
public struct logevent  
{  
public ContextType context;  
public struct ContextType  
{  
  public string[] severity;  
}  
}
```

However, when I tried to access an element of the 'serverity' using a line,

```
String temp = logevent.context.severity.GetValue(0).ToString()
```

, the program throws a following error:

```
"Index was outside the bounds of the array."
```

When I changed the element from 'unbounded' to '1' in the XSD file and also modified 'public string[] severity;' to 'public string severity;', it works.

Can anyone help me to make the web service to accept a message including unbounded numbers of elements?

Comment: Are you sure there was an element in the `severity` array? What was the value of `logevent.context.severity.Length`? Also, ASMX web service or WCF?

Comment: Can you give the SOAP/XML message sent to the web service.

Comment: Thanks John for your reply! the value of logevent.context.severity.Length is 0. It seems that the application cannot detect it when it is made an array. I created this service as a 'ASP.NET Web Service Application'.

Comment: Thanks Richard! The message sent to the service is following (sorry for that I'm not sure how I can format this well.):   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <LogMessage xmlns="http://loggingservice.something.com/">
   <logevent>
    <context>
     <severity>123</severity>
     <severity>456</severity>
    </context>
   </logevent>
  </LogMessage>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: Please show more of the code. For instance, where is `avantlog`?

Comment: BTW, if you created it as you say you did, then you made a mistake and started new development using a legacy technology.

Answer (score 1):

The code that corresponds to specified XSD (if serialized using XmlSerializer) is the following:

```
[XmlRoot("LogMessage"]
public class LogMessage
{
    [XmlElement("avantlog")]
    public LogEventType AvantLog {get; set;}
}

public class LogEventType
{
    [XmlArray("context")]
    [XmlArrayItem("severity")]
    public string[] Severity {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use attributes in order to control the deserialization of the incoming XML.  By default, the supported XML structure for arrays follows the form:

```
<Elements>
  <Element>X</Element>
  <Element>Y</Element>
</Element>
```

However, your WSDL specifies unbounded "Element" terms and does not provide for a parent "Elements" block.  My understanding is that in order to use unbounded terms, you need to specify attributes to control the deserialization, as unbounded terms are not the default in .NET WSDL generation and deserialization.

This article discusses how to control deserialization using attributes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx

Comment: Please don't post .NET 1.1 links unless your answer is specific to .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your XSD to a POCO object using "XSD.exe" and then use XmlSerializer. This will make it easy to interact with multiple external systems via XML. Might want to use SGen.exe as well to increase `XmlSerializer` Performance. Hope this Helps

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm